# Can I use Environment.Username and MYSQL to verify log in?

Tags: c#, mysql, authentication

```
        private void btnSubmitt_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
        try
        {
            i = 0;
            MySqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "Select * from users where  TX_EMPLOYEE='"; (Environment.UserName) & "'";
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dt);

            i = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows.Count.ToString());
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Database connection is not available at this time. Please contact your database administrator ");
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
```

I would like to authenticate the user with their computer login name and the exact match that is listed in the MYSQL data table. However Environment.Username is not a valid syntax in this SQL statement.

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem or are you still struggling? If it didn't, please edit your question to include more details and tag me (@john) so that I can look at it.

Comment: @john Yes, you did! I'm sorry I'm new to stack overflow and also new to coding. I was able to correct that. However, I moved MYSQL database to SQL Server and I'm currently experiencing some issues with my connection string. More specifically I received an "Unrecognized escape sequence" and I tired using "@'" and even "\\" but it was not successful.

Answer (score 3):

This line is very very wrong:

```
cmd.CommandText = "Select * from users where  TX_EMPLOYEE='"; (Environment.UserName) & "'";
```

It should be this:

```
cmd.CommandText = "Select * from users where  TX_EMPLOYEE='" + Environment.UserName + "'";
```

Except, it shouldn't be like that because of SQL injection. If I could make `Environment.UserName` into `' or 1 = 1 or TX_EMPLOYEE = '` then your final query would become this:

```
Select * from users where  TX_EMPLOYEE='' or 1 = 1 or TX_EMPLOYEE = ''
```

Which clearly isn't what you want - somebody with no credentials being able to access this. You should instead use SQL parameters:

```
cmd.CommandText = "Select * from users where  TX_EMPLOYEE=?userName";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?userName", Environment.UserName);
```

On a separate note, I'm confused by this code:

```
i = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows.Count.ToString());
```

[DataTable.Rows.Count](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarowcollection.count?view=netframework-4.8) is already an `int`, so you're converting a number to a string to a number. Why?

Comment: I moved my database to a SQL Server environment and it looks like cmd.CommandText = "Select * from users where  TX_EMPLOYEE=?userName";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?userName", Environment.UserName); is not the correct syntax

Comment: Yes, for SQL server you'll need to change to `@userName`. `?userName` is for MySQL.

Comment: it's still incorrect. I'm getting the following error (Must declare the scalar variable "@userName") and I'm using Select * from [Users] where [TX_EMPLOYEE]=@userName

Comment: Are you adding the parameter to the command? `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userName", Environment.UserName);`?

Comment: Yes (cmd.CommandText = "Select * from [Users] where [TX_EMPLOYEE]=@userName";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userName", Environment.UserName);

Comment: And this is SQL Server?

Comment: Yes. I did as much research as I could and I saw that some people were using (int UserExist = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();) but I was not sure how to find that into my code and I think. I also don't think I need to use an "int"